# Mysql2::Error Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) ruby on rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, mysql2

I installed Ruby on Rails 4.2 on Ubuntu successfully and am using MySQL as my database but when I want to see the new app I created on the browser using localhost:3000

I get this error message:

```
Mysql2::Error
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Extracted source (around line #70):


        socket = socket.to_s unless socket.nil?

70      connect user, pass, host, port, database, socket, flags
      end

      def self.default_query_options
```

Any help?

Comment: This is a connection problem, are the configurations in your `config/database.yml` correct?

Comment: what is your mysql password for root user ? update your `config/database.yml` with password of your root user.

Comment: Have you tested that your database allows access for user root with no password at host localhost?

Answer (score 0):

I installed Ruby 2.2, ROR 4.2.0, mysql server 5.6 on my Mac OS 10.9 and tested my first ROR application. 
Rails App use sqlite3 database as default and I try to use mysql this time.

Here's my steps:

1. Use the CLI: **rails new my_app -d mysql**.
2. Go to my_app directory and start rails server by CLI: **rails s**.
3. Visit address with http://localhost:3000
4. Then, got the same question like yours: **an Mysql2 Error**.
   Just try to check the file: **my_app/config/database.yml**

   Solution: Give password value to the root user. ( which should keep consistent with mysql that configured before).
5. Restart rails server.
6. Then, Got another Mysql2 error saying: **unknown database XXX**.

   Solution: which because ROR cannot find the database XXX. Go to my_app directory and create database with CLI: **rake db:create**.
7. Restart rails server and visit http://localhost:3000. OK!